# Excel: Check whether a cell has text in another cell and with symbol, or trim left and right

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, worksheet-function, worksheet

So i have cell from long text from formula witch

> =RIGHT(J2;15)
>
> 2016-07-22 2016

How to take out both 2016- and 2016 using find? It needs to be variable since in 2017 it wont be 2016. Can i find using something like FIND(K2&"-";J2)? Example below.

Result i need to get only 07

I used

> =MID(LEFT(J2;FIND(N2;J2)-5);FIND(K2;J2)+5;LEN(J2))

But it finds both of 2016 and gives nothing

Wanted to something like

> =MID(LEFT(J2;FIND(N2;J2)-5);FIND(K2&"-";J2)+5;LEN(J2))

But doesnt work

Comment: Is `2016-07-22 2016` a text string or a real date with a custom number format of `yyyy-mm-dd yyyy` ? Does `=REPLACE(H10, IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(32), J2), LEN(J2)), LEN(J2), TEXT(,))` work?

Comment: Its a text only

Comment: You could also try `=TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(J2, 10)), "mm")`.

Comment: WOW. and how i get now only result 22? WOW got it dd for day! Add as soluton so i can check it! ALso for others when it would be not numbers but like John-Sue-Lark-John Santa   how to do then.

Comment: Change `mm` to `dd`. Here's a link to [Number Format Codes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68).

Comment: Add as andswer. following link im putting for me as bookmark for topic http://www.ficpa.org/content/Sections/biztech/News/Tips/CellsContainSame.aspx

Comment: @Jeeped add as solution ill check it as done

Comment: @Jeeped add as solution ill check it as done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling the left 10 characters off the text string should allow direct conversion to a true date using the [DATEVALUE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-DF8B07D4-7761-4A93-BC33-B7471BBFF252) function (possibly assuming the conputer's correct system DMY vs. MDY regional setting). Once that true date has been achieved, a wrapping [TEXT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20D5AC4D-7B94-49FD-BB38-93D29371225C) function can resolve any part of the date (e.g. year, month or day).

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(J2, 10)), "mm")      ◄ month as text representing a number
=--TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(J2, 10)), "mm")    ◄ month as true number
```